# How to read item data from sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

creating a scheduled script, want to get values from the standard record on item sublist how do i do that ?

```
function execute(scriptContext) {

   var poid = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter("custscriptbb1_mga_po_id");


   var objRecord = record.load({ 
       type: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER, 
       id: poid,
       isDynamic: false,
       });

   var itemvalue = objRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'item'
    });

   var rate = objRecord.getValue({
    fieldId: 'item'
   });


log.debug("itemvalue: "+ itemvalue + "rate  "+rate);
```

Answer (score 1):

To read data from sublist you need to use [record.getSublistValue](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273166148.html) or [record.getCurrentSublistValue](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273170578.html) where your parameters should be something as below.

```
{
  sublistId: 'item',
  fieldId: 'item',
  line: LINE_NO
}
```

To log all the line items with rate of a give record, you can use the below

```
var itemCount = poRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });

for (var line = 0; line < itemCount; line++) {
  log.debug({ 
    title: 'line#' + line, 
    details: {
      item: poRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', line: line }),
      rate: poRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'rate', line: line }),
    } 
  });
}
```

**Note:** *getCurrentSublistValue* can only be used ub dynamic mode and you have to select the line using *selectLine* method first.